# flutter_BottomNavigationBar_Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

using the BottomNavigationBar
I get the following error:
Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const BottomNavigationBarItem({

my code is the next one:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items:[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                title:Text('Hola'),
                icon:  (Icons.calendar_today),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon (Icons.pie_chart_outlined),
                  title:Text('hola'),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon (Icons.supervised_user_circle),
                title:Text('hola'),
              ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: could you please provide the code properly and the chunck of code where you have called bottomNavigationBar ...

Comment: try using lable instead of text and see if this resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the argument name for icon in `BottomNavigationBar`

Like this:
`BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit), label: 'my label')`

Answer (score 0):

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.business),
        label: 'Business',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.school),
        label: 'School',
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. It had two flaws:

1. the "title" parameter is already obsolete
2. I forgot to put the Icon class, a pretty big mistake

Thank you